# No class template named 'apply' with regard to Boost Signals2

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, signals

I have followed the Boost tutorial, "Passing Slots (Intermediate)", at reference [ 1 ] to the letter yet I am getting a weird error with my code that I cannot decipher or find any help with regard to. My code is below:

[ 1 ] - http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/signals2/tutorial.html#idp204830936

```
namespace GekkoFyre {
class TuiHangouts {
private:
    typedef boost::signals2::signal<void()> onRosterUpdate;
    typedef onRosterUpdate::slot_type onRosterUpdateSlotType;

    void logMsgs(std::string message, const xmppMsgType &msgType);
    void logMsgsDrawHistory();

    // Slots
    boost::signals2::connection doOnRosterUpdate(const onRosterUpdateSlotType &slot);
    onRosterUpdate rosterUpdate;
};
}

boost::signals2::connection GekkoFyre::TuiHangouts::doOnRosterUpdate(
        const GekkoFyre::TuiHangouts::onRosterUpdateSlotType &slot)
{
    return rosterUpdate.connect(slot);
}
```

The problem is with this specifically:

```
void GekkoFyre::TuiHangouts::logMsgs(std::string message, const xmppMsgType &msgType)
{
    doOnRosterUpdate(&GekkoFyre::TuiHangouts::logMsgsDrawHistory);
}
```

I get the error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/function/detail/maybe_include.hpp:13:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/function/detail/function_iterate.hpp:14,
                 from /usr/include/boost/preprocessor/iteration/detail/iter/forward1.hpp:47,
                 from /usr/include/boost/function.hpp:64,
                 from /usr/include/boost/signals2/signal.hpp:18,
                 from /usr/include/boost/signals2.hpp:19,
                 from /home/phobos/Programming/gecho/src/tui/chat.hpp:47,
                 from /home/phobos/Programming/gecho/src/tui/chat.cpp:35:
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp: In instantiation of 'void boost::function0<R>::assign_to(Functor) [with Functor = void (GekkoFyre::TuiHangouts::*)(); R = void]':
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:722:7:   required from 'boost::function0<R>::function0(Functor, typename boost::enable_if_c<(boost::type_traits::ice_not<(boost::is_integral<Functor>::value)>::value), int>::type) [with Functor = void (GekkoFyre::TuiHangouts::*)(); R = void; typename boost::enable_if_c<(boost::type_traits::ice_not<(boost::is_integral<Functor>::value)>::value), int>::type = int]'
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:1071:16:   required from 'boost::function<R()>::function(Functor, typename boost::enable_if_c<(boost::type_traits::ice_not<(boost::is_integral<Functor>::value)>::value), int>::type) [with Functor = void (GekkoFyre::TuiHangouts::*)(); R = void; typename boost::enable_if_c<(boost::type_traits::ice_not<(boost::is_integral<Functor>::value)>::value), int>::type = int]'
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:1126:5:   required from 'typename boost::enable_if_c<(boost::type_traits::ice_not<(boost::is_integral<Functor>::value)>::value), boost::function<R()>&>::type boost::function<R()>::operator=(Functor) [with Functor = void (GekkoFyre::TuiHangouts::*)(); R = void; typename boost::enable_if_c<(boost::type_traits::ice_not<(boost::is_integral<Functor>::value)>::value), boost::function<R()>&>::type = boost::function<void()>&]'
/usr/include/boost/signals2/detail/slot_template.hpp:160:24:   required from 'void boost::signals2::slot<R(Args ...), SlotFunction>::init_slot_function(const F&) [with F = void (GekkoFyre::TuiHangouts::*)(); SlotFunction = boost::function<void()>; R = void; Args = {}]'
/usr/include/boost/signals2/detail/slot_template.hpp:85:27:   required from 'boost::signals2::slot<R(Args ...), SlotFunction>::slot(const F&) [with F = void (GekkoFyre::TuiHangouts::*)(); SlotFunction = boost::function<void()>; R = void; Args = {}]'
/home/phobos/Programming/gecho/src/tui/chat.cpp:802:74:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:924:9: error: no class template named 'apply' in 'struct boost::detail::function::get_invoker0<boost::detail::function::member_ptr_tag>'
         handler_type;
```

If anyone could assist with this then it would be immensely appreciated. As I said previously, I did some research and couldn't really find much of anything. It seems kind of unique to me, perhaps, and I did follow the tutorial to the letter. I know this isn't always the right thing to do but from what I can gather through research, this code should work.

Comment: `&GekkoFyre::TuiHangouts::logMsgsDrawHistory` is a member function pointer, but you're not providing a `this` pointer anywhere.

Comment: @Simple, `doOnRosterUpdate(this->logMsgsDrawHistory);` gives "Invalid use of non-static member function" and `doOnRosterUpdate(&GekkoFyre::TuiHangouts::logMsgsDrawHistory, this);` gives `no matching function for call to 'GekkoFyre::TuiHangouts::doOnRosterUpdate(void (GekkoFyre::TuiHangouts::*)`.

Comment: No, you need to learn about how member function pointers work. I assume you can use Boost.Bind, so try `doOnRosterUpdate(boost::bind(&GekkoFyre::TuiHangouts::logMsgsDrawHistory, this));`.

Comment: Oh neat, I didn't even know about boost::bind(). But thank you! You've also given me something to read up on, @Simple :)

Answer (score 1):

`&GekkoFyre::TuiHangouts::logMsgsDrawHistory` is a member function pointer, which has the type `void (GekkoFyre::TuiHangouts::*)()`. This isn't like any other function, and so it cannot be called like any other function. Signals2 will attempt to call this with the syntax `func()`, but there is no `this` pointer here. To provide it with a `this` pointer, you would use the syntax `(p->*func)()`. The `p` here becomes the `this` pointer. `boost::bind` (also in the C++ standard since 2011 called `std::bind`) will wrap this up as a function object that *can* be called as `func()` by calling `(p->*func)()`.